# How to flash Yocto Images directly using clonezilla

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

We are using meta-intel layer to generate .hddimg.

We can flash the generated .hddimg using Bootable Thumb Drive, but using this mechanism in manufacturing is not a good solution.

We need some way to flash the Yocto Image using clonezilla, hddimg is not recognized by clonezilla.

Do we need to add any IMAGE_FSTYPES to make it work. Or is there any other solutions to flash Yocto Images over PXE Boot

Thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 1):

IMAGE_FSTYPES just sets the build output image extension. With the IMAGE_FSTYPES variable, you can get partitioned image or unpartitoned image separetly.

Also you can create a recipe then, you can generate a new partitioned image according to the your needs but, As I know clonezilla can handle the raw images("dd") and yocto can able to generate raw images. I use the raw image most of the time and clonezilla can handle the raw images.

Comment: So dd images work with clonezilla?, hddimg of yocto is installer which allows you to boot from USB and then install on the target.. which format should yocto generate for raw image

Comment: in the clonezilla, you can generate a backup which is by dd. In the device to device backup you can see the "dd" option. 

you can revise the current image recipes in the yocto folder. In the meta/classes directory, you can find the recipes about image types like image.bbclass.

Also there is one more way, you can get the backup with the clonezilla in the end product then, you can use in the production but it is not a good way to modify something.

Comment: Can't we directly apply a dd image generated by Yocto using clonezilla. I don't want to have a two step process of flashing the dd image using USB and then dd using Clonezilla

Comment: I did not apply the operation to the hdd. If you you write .hddimg to the your harddisk. You should could flash the image with clonezilla.